# Filtering multiple inner join

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT courses.id as course_id, student_courses.student_id FROM courses
    INNER JOIN tutor_courses ON courses.id = tutor_courses.course_id
    INNER JOIN student_courses ON courses.id = student_courses.course_id
    INNER JOIN students ON students.id = student_courses.student_id
    WHERE tutor_courses.tutor_id = '201'
    GROUP BY course_id,student_id;
```

I get the next result:

```
course_id, student_id
'100', '30'
'104', '20'
'101', '100'
'104', '200'
'100', '20'
```

I also have a table, called contacts:

```
id, course_id, student_id, contact_datetime, review
```

This table, store the reviews with the date. So a student can have multiple reviews, but just one for every day / course.

Now, I would like to filter my first query with the contacts table, and show just the results where using a selected contact_datetime is null.

Should I use a LEFT JOIN on the first query? or maybe create a new query for it?

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

Only use outer join if there's no row. Having a row with a null column can be easily handled with inner join too.

```
SELECT courses.id as course_id, student_courses.student_id FROM courses
    INNER JOIN tutor_courses ON courses.id = tutor_courses.course_id
    INNER JOIN student_courses ON courses.id = student_courses.course_id
    INNER JOIN students ON students.id = student_courses.student_id
    INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.course_id = courses.id and contacts.student_id = students.id
    WHERE tutor_courses.tutor_id = '201' and contacts.contact_datetime is null
    GROUP BY course_id,student_id;
```